# It is not possible to select a select option

Tags: watir, ruby-watir

I'm trying to select a value from my select field:

```
<select class="form-control select required chosen-select" name="shopping_cart[kind]" id="shopping_cart_kind" style="display: none;"> 
     <option value="">Selecione</option>
     <option value="pdc">PDC</option>
     <option value="normal">Cotação Normal</option>
     <option value="emergency">Cotação Emergencial</option>
     <option value="contract">Cotação para Contrato</option>
     <option value="price_research">Pesquisa de Preço</option>
     <option value="legal_purchase">Compra Judicial</option>
     <option value="bidding_exemption">Dispensa de Licitação</option>
     <option value="scheduled_delivery">Cotação para entrega programada</option></select>
```

In my code I'm trying to set the second option:

```
@type = @browser.select_list(id: "shopping_cart_kind")
@type.select 'PDC'
```

And I have received this error:

```
timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:id=>"shopping_cart_kind", :tag_name=>"select"} to become present (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
```

I've tried the following alternatives and they did not work:

- Click element via javascript:

  @browser.execute_script( "return arguments[0].click();", browser.link(:id => 'shopping_cart_kind')
- Select by index:

  @browser.select_list(id: "shopping_cart_kind", index: 1).select ("PDC")
  @browser.select_list(id: "shopping_cart_kind").option[1].select

Nothing worked!

Comment: Something is indicating that the Select List is not displayed on the page. Can you verify what version of Watir you are using?

Comment: The select list has `style="display: none;"`, which is why Watir is timing out waiting for it to be present. Are you sure that users directly interact with that select list? A lot of pages have custom dropdown looking controls that are actually links/divs/etc. While the custom control might populate the select list eventually, it's not what the user interacts with and is therefore not what Watir can interact with.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this code and let me know whether it works?

```
@type = @browser.select_list(id: "shopping_cart_kind")
@type.option(text: 'PDC').select
```

Comment: **I had tried it and received the error:**

`2018-12-28 14:02:02 WARN Watir [DEPRECATION] ["until", "timeout_arguments"] Using arguments for Wait#until is deprecated. Use keywords instead.
    And I fill the quotation required fields # features/step_definitions/create_quotation.rb:5
      element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Option: located: true; {:id=>"shopping_cart_kind", :tag_name=>"select"} --> {:text=>"PDC", :tag_name=>"option"}> to be present`

Comment: Then your option is not visible, you don't have any problem when you choose the option manually?